# Setting name for a docker image

Tags: docker, build

I forgot to include a name tag during docker build. I have the image id now, how do I assign it a name? 
I used the documentation but I still don't know if it's possible.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_tag/#usage

I did docker image id New_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Docker tag, the man-page states the following:

> Docker tag SOURCE_NAME [:TAG] TARGET_NAME[:TAG]
>
> "Assigns a new alias to an image in a registry. An alias refers to the
>   entire image name including the optional TAG after the ':'."

So by doing:
docker tag [your image id] [a name for your image]:[a tag] you will tag the image and it will be available under that name/tag